# Visual Studio 2015: v120 vs v140?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker, visual-studio-2015, freeglut

FYI: Win10, x64

I started trying out Visual Studio 2015 today, and after figuring out how to get the C/C++ parts running I tried to load up a big personal project that uses the [unofficial glsdk](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html).  I tried to build and got linker errors.  It complained about unresolved external symbols being referenced in freeglutD.lib, glloadD.lib, and glutil.lib.  It also complained about _MSC_VER mismatches in my own files.

I did some research online, messed around with 2013 and compiler versions (project properties -> General -> Platform Toolset)) - v120 for 2013 and v140 for 2015 - and was able to rebuild glsdk with v140 (excluding glmesh due to a missing file).  Then...it worked fine.

**Question:** Why is this?  I thought that a static lib file created by a standard-compliant compiler would work with other versions of a standard-compliant compiler (in this case, C/C++ on v120 and C/C++ on v140).  But apparently v140 would not play ball with libraries made by a previous compiler.

If this is just the dark lands of VS build routines, then I can drop the question, but I'd also like to know why they don't work together.

Comment: http://siomsystems.com/mixing-visual-studio-versions/ Does this help?  It's too long to repeat here :)

Comment: This is the way VC++ works - brand new libraries for each new release.

Comment: Linking code that was built with an old version of the compiler's .h files and C++ standard library to the new version of the runtime code is a pretty risky proposition..  Especially of late with C++11, 14 and 17 design changes.  Might work, might not and produce truly baffling memory corruption errors.  The MSVC++ compiler has a 1-800 support phone number.  If you ask the people that pick up that phone which is better, "force them to recompile or take the risk?", they always have the same answer.  Which inspired the _MSC_VER checks.  You can defeat them but it is little late now :)

Comment: New libraries for each release?  I don't remember having to recompile the glsdk for VS 2013.  Must have forgotten.

Answer (score 2):

Historically, Visual C++ has broken binary compatibility between the run-time libraries at each major version.  This provides some freedom to improve implementations without being constrained by the ABIs of previous versions.

Starting with Visual C++ 2015, however, they've re-architected the run-time libraries in a way that should allow them to provide compatibility going forward, but this doesn't solve the problem going backwards.

See this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/) and the few follow-ups they've posted about the "Universal CRT."

Comment: The link migrated [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/)

Comment: @RadicalEd:  Thanks!  I've updated the link in the post.