# Compile QT and append a suffix to the generated DLLs name

Tags: visual-studio, qt, dll, compilation

Due to [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036696/invalid-mex-function), I need to compile QT and generate the whole set of libs and DLLs with a custom suffix. Something like Qt5Core_MySuffix.dll, Qt5Gui_MySuffix.dll, Qt5Core_MySuffix.lib, and so on...

How can I do that? I am using [this](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/22/how-to-build-qt-5-7-statically-using-msvc14-microsoft-visual-studio-2015/) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj41yY2Q1Bo) tutorials to perform the compilation.

Do I need to edit the configure.bat file?

Environment:
Windows7
MSVC2015

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted

Comment: why do you think Qt is a problem? MEX-file has nothing common with Qt.

Comment: It is indeed a strange conclusion, but it makes sense..  Simulink is built using QT (check /bin folder fo matlab) If simulink is open, it means Qt5Gui.dll is loaded. But not the same version I am using ... ps: my mex functions opens a GUI built with simulink.  ps2: Also, I debugged my mex function. If I remove any qt reference, it works... Otherwise it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on configuration step. Where is an option `qtlibinfix`:

```
-qtlibinfix <infix> Renames all Qt* libs to Qt*<infix>.
```

Just add it to the configure command from you [link](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/22/how-to-build-qt-5-7-statically-using-msvc14-microsoft-visual-studio-2015/):

```
configure -static -qtlibinfix MyInFix -debug-and-release -prefix “C:\Qt\Static\5.7.0” -platform win32-msvc2015 -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -qt-sql-sqlite -qt-sql-odbc -no-openssl -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if the BUG with not adding InFix to the Qt plugins is fixed. If not, you can easily fix it yourself. Take a look [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15192)